# LINQ select should break on first match

Tags: c#, linq

I want to convert the following structured code into a more readable LINQ call:

```cs
foreach (string line in this.HeaderTexts)
{
    Match match = dimensionsSearcher.Match(line);

    if (match.Success)
    {
        // Do something
        return;
    }
}
```

I came up with the following code:

```cs
Match foundMatch = this.HeaderTexts
    .Select(text => dimensionsSearcher.Match(text))
    .Where(match => match.Success)
    .FirstOrDefault();

if (foundMatch != null)
{
    // Do something
    return;
}
```

However, from my understanding, this will run the Regex check for each header text, while my first code breaks as soon as it hits for the first time. Is there a way to optimize the LINQ version of that code, of should I rather stick to the structural code?

Comment: "However, from my understanding, this will run the Regex check for each header text" - where does that understanding come from, and have you validated it? (Hint: it won't.)

Comment: Note that you could change it to `...Select(...).FirstOrDefault(match => match.Success);` as well.

Comment: @JonSkeet It doesn't? I always thought that it will run the checks and manipulations from left to right. So it doesn't do that?

Comment: @JonSkeet Oh, that sounds even nicer!

Comment: You may want to read my Edulinq blog post series: https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/category/edulinq/ - but fundamentally LINQ to Objects evaluates lazily where it can.

Comment: Perhaps you are thinking of `ToList()` or similar method which will force evaluation of every item in the collection (depending on the source type).

Comment: @TimSchmelter: Well, it depends on what you mean by "other methods" - there are methods that interrupt the lazy evaluation, even if it's still partially deferred. `OrderBy()` and `Reverse()` for example.

Comment: @BurnsBA Exactly that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's say you have a list of integers, you need to add 2 to each number, then find the first one that is even.

```
var input = new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
var firstEvenNumber = input
    .Select(x => x + 2)
    .Where(x => x % 2 == 0)
    .First();

// firstEvenNumber is 4, which is the input "2" plus two
```

Now, does the `Select` evaluate `x + 2` on every input before `First` gets ran? Let's find out. We can replace the code in `Select` with a multi-line lambda to print to the console when it's evaluated.

```
var input = new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };

var firstEvenNumber = input
    .Select(x => {
        Console.WriteLine($"Processing {x}");
        return x + 2;
    })
    .Where(x => x % 2 == 0)
    .First();

Console.WriteLine("First even number is " + firstEvenNumber);
```

This prints:

```
Processing 1
Processing 2
First even number is 4
```

So it looks like Linq only evaluated the minimum number of entries needed to satisfy `Where` and `First`.

`Where` and `First` doesn't need *all* the processed records up-front in order to pass to the next step unlike `Reverse()`, `ToList()`, `OrderBy()`, etc.

If you instead stuck a `ToList()` before `First`, it would be a different story.

```
var input = new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };

var firstEvenNumber = input
    .Select(x => {
        Console.WriteLine($"Processing {x}");
        return x + 2;
    })
    .Where(x => x % 2 == 0)
    .ToList() // same thing if you put it before Where instead
    .First();

Console.WriteLine("First even number is " + firstEvenNumber);
```

This prints:

```
Processing 1
Processing 2
Processing 3
Processing 4
Processing 5
Processing 6
First even number is 4
```

Answer (score 3):

Your LINQ query does what you hope it does. It will only execute the regex until one header matches. So it has the same behavior as your loop. That's ensured with `FirstOrDefault` (or `First`). You could rewrite it to:

```
Match foundMatch = this.HeaderTexts
    .Select(text => dimensionsSearcher.Match(text))
    .FirstOrDefault(m => m.Success);
// ...
```

Note that `Single` and `SingleOrDefault` ensure that there is at maximum one match(otherwise they throw an `InvalidOperationException`), so they might need to enumerate all because they have to check if there is a second match.

Read this blog if you want to understand how lazy evaluation(deferred execution) works:
https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/category/edulinq/